# Azure OpenAI - Encryption in Transit

Tags: azure, azure-openai

For Azure Open AI, Encryption at rest is built using Microsoft Managed Keys --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/encrypt-data-at-rest.

Is **encryption** in **transit** occurring via the trained validation data sets?

An example: I want to train my data using Azure blob. I know I can configure my storage account to only accept TLS 1.2 connections. However, I don’t appear to have the option of configuring how I want to *obtain* the data. Is my data being passed via TLS 1.2 between the blob and the training infrastructure.

Comment: I've reached out to Microsoft, will send an answer when they get back to me. Presumably they will update their wiki.

Comment: has anyone heard back about this? The documentation still doesn't cover this topic